# Nginx proxy_pass WordPress to another server

Tags: wordpress

I have to use a proxy_pass because I have a main application on / and I want to run WordPress on another server. This is required because my software has multiple servers (load balancing). So the following situation:

```
server1.com/ is my app
server2.com/ is my app

server1.com/wordpress proxy_pass to server3/wordpress
server2.com/wordpress proxy_pass to server3/wordpress
```

This all works, but when I want to login it keeps redirecting me to the login page after logging in.

My config looks like this of nginx:

```
location /wordpress {
    proxy_pass http://server3.nl:80/wordpress/;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

In my wordpress wp-config.php I had to fix the following lines in order to make this work:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://maindomain/wordpress/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://maindomain/wordpress/');

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this redirect?

Comment: What if you replace 'http://server3.nl:80/wordpress/' with 'https://maindomain/wordpress/' ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add one more directive into your config

```
proxy_set_header Host      $host;
```

If not then i would look into [proxy_cookie_path](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_path) directive.

I think issue is with cookie domain

Answer (score -1):

Have this as your configuration:

```
location /wordpress {
    proxy_pass http://server3.nl:80/wordpress/;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```